# In MySQL get an error: #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am trying to `UNION` comments and posts from Drupal and phpBB tables.

This is my SQL:

```
(
SELECT  f.forum_name AS section,
        p.topic_id,
        p.forum_id,
        p.post_id,
        p.poster_id AS uid,
        u.username AS user,
        p.post_time AS post_time,
        p.post_subject AS subject
FROM phpbb_posts p
JOIN phpbb_forums f ON f.forum_id = p.forum_id
JOIN phpbb_topics t ON p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id
JOIN phpbb_users u ON p.poster_id = u.user_id
)
UNION (

SELECT  NULL AS section,
        comments.nid AS topic_id,
        NULL AS forum_id,
        comments.cid AS post_id,
        comments.uid AS uid,
        comments.name AS user,
        comments.timestamp AS post_time,
        comments.subject AS subject
FROM dr_node node
LEFT JOIN dr_comments comments ON node.nid = comments.nid
WHERE node.status =1
)
ORDER BY post_time DESC
LIMIT 7
```

and it gives me

> error: #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Where is the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: comment out everything in your select clauses except for section.  Run the query.  If it fails, the problem is likely because you are selecting null.  You can fix that by selecting an empty string.  If it succeeds, add the fields back to your select clauses one by one until it fails.  The last field you added will have caused the problem.

Comment: check the "Character Set", check this thread http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,27204,27204#msg-27204

Comment: I have just figured out, that it is because of column subject. What can I do with it? The SET command doesn't help.

Comment: Did you ever figure out your column subject issue figured out? Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346604/why-is-the-community-user-so-determined-to-bump-this-question?cb=1

Comment: Please post your "update" as an answer, and then 48 hours later when the site allows you, accept it. Leaving this question open is not useful to the community. More: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I've made the edit a community wiki answer. It can be removed if the OP returns and wants to post the answer themselves. (Please just comment on the community wiki answer and I can remove it)

Comment: I voted to close as no repro

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution that worked for the OP (taken from question):

I have just found solution. Problem was with subject column. I added `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` to the subject in the second `SELECT`.

```
(
SELECT  f.forum_name AS section,
        p.topic_id,
        p.forum_id,
        p.post_id,
        p.poster_id AS uid,
        u.username AS user,
        p.post_time AS post_time,
        p.post_subject AS subject
FROM phpbb_posts p
JOIN phpbb_forums f ON f.forum_id = p.forum_id
JOIN phpbb_topics t ON p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id
JOIN phpbb_users u ON p.poster_id = u.user_id
)
UNION (

SELECT  NULL AS section,
        comments.nid AS topic_id,
        NULL AS forum_id,
        comments.cid AS post_id,
        comments.uid AS uid,
        comments.name AS user,
        comments.timestamp AS post_time,
        comments.subject COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS subject 
FROM dr_node node
LEFT JOIN dr_comments comments ON node.nid = comments.nid
WHERE node.status =1
)
ORDER BY post_time DESC
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Check both your tables `phpbb_posts` and `dr_node` collation. Most probably, they are created with different collation like one with `latine` and another with `utf-8`. Hence, you are facing this issue.

**EDIT:**

You should have both tables with same collation; but in your case as pointed by @Dan; it's most probably that you are trying to make comparison between `f.forum_name AS section` in first query with `NULL as section` in your second query. [As you already mentioned your query works from PHPMyAdmin].

So as stated [in this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,27204,27214#msg-27214)

Try setting wither of this and how it goes.

```
SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci;
```

or

```
SET character_set_connection = utf8;
```

Comment: dr_node is utf8_general_ci and phpbb_posts is utf8_bin. What should I do with it?

Comment: I have tried both. Same error

Comment: I added the SET command before the first SELECT